# JavaScript crashing due to HTML entities in JSON string

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, razor

I am using `NewtonSoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` to serialize an ASP.NET Dictionary object into a JSON string. I then pass this string to my MVC View by means of the ViewBag.

When I in my MVC Razor by Razor syntax try to load the JSON string from the ViewBag and into a JavaScript variabe my JavaScript crashes due to syntax error. When I inspect the source code I find this:

```
var hf = {&quot;Test0&quot;:65,&quot;Test1&quot;:23,&quot;Test2&quot;:43,&quot;Test3&quot;:6,&quot;Test4&quot;:31,&quot;Test5&quot;:78,&quot;Test6&quot;:1,&quot;Test7&quot;:53,&quot;Test8&quot;:74,&quot;Test9&quot;:54};
```

This my logic for loading the contents of the ViewBag in the View:

```
@section RenderChart
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    function drawChart() {
        var hf = @ViewBag.ChartJsonData;
```

For some reason my JSON string is being HTML encoded. I tried passing it into the ViewBag after running it through `Server.HtmlDecode()` but that did not help. Does anyone know how I can decode this string or pass it to the JavaScript in my MVC View without it being converted to HTML entities?

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of view where you output the JSON from the ViewBag?

Comment: @nemesv Ah yes, sorry for leaving that out! I have updated the original post now with the relevant code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Razor automatically HTML encodes every string if it was outputted with the `@`.

If you don't want the HTML encoding you need to wrap your string with a [Html.Raw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.98%29.aspx):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    function drawChart() {
        var hf = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.ChartJsonData)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Of course! I had forgotten about that. Been too long since I did web programming. Thank you so much!